# accessing javascript through java in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

My code currently looks like this

```
<%
    if (request != null) {
        bustOut;
    }
%>

<script language="javascript">
function bustOut(){
   var newWin = window.open("the real url", "subWindow","height=500,width=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes"); 
}
</script>
```

How do I call the javascript function inside the Java code? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP runs at webserver and generates/produces HTML/CSS/JS code upon a webbrowser request. Webserver sends HTML/CSS/JS to webbrowser. Webbrowser runs HTML/CSS/JS. So, you just have to let JSP print it literally as JS code.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function bustOut(){
       var newWin = window.open("the real url", "subWindow","height=500,width=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes"); 
    }
    <% 
        if (foo != null) { 
            out.print("bustOut();");
        }
    %>
</script>
```

or, [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), with EL

```
<script language="javascript">
    function bustOut(){
       var newWin = window.open("the real url", "subWindow","height=500,width=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes"); 
    }
    ${not empty foo ? 'bustOut();' : ''}
</script>
```

*(note that I changed the attribute name to `foo` because `request` stands for `HttpServletRequest` which might confuse others since this is never `null`)*

Either way, the generated HTML (which you should see by opening page in browser, rightclicking it and choosing *View Source*) should look like this when the condition was true:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function bustOut(){
       var newWin = window.open("the real url", "subWindow","height=500,width=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes"); 
    }
    bustOut();
</script>
```

Does it now turn on a light bulb above your head?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call javascript functions from java

Your java code is executed on the server, and the javascript - on the client.

What you seem to need is conditionally open a new window on document load. For that:

```
<c:if test="${shouldDisplayWindow}">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         bustOut();
     });
</c:if>
```

(that's jQuery above for detecting document load. You can replace it with pure javascript - `window.onload = function() {..}` or `document.onload = function() {..}` I think)

Note that `request != null` is meaningless condition - the request is never `null` in a JSP.

And finally - use jstl tags (like I showed) and not java code (scriptlets).